# SQLite, NetBeans, EclipseLink and JPA - NetBeans keeps starting Apache Derby instead of SQLite DB

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, jpa, netbeans

I'm struggling with NetBeans and failing to make a project (Vaadin -> **Maven**-based) that connects to an SQLite database. For some reason every time I run my project:

- NetBeans starts an Apache Derby database
- JPA doesn't generate tables in my SQLite table (probably since I never manage to connect to it)

I have done the following:

1. **"Install" the SQLite JDBC driver** - downloaded the jar, went to *Services -> Database* and created a new connection pointing at the jar. I've named it *SQLite 3.8.11.2*. It has been successfully added and listed under *Databases -> Drivers*.
2. **Adding a connection to the database** - the database is created using the command line tool and is located inside the root directory of the NetBeans Maven project. Currently it is empty since I want to use JPA to generate my tables from the respective entity classes. I added the connection and it points to the `cookbook.sqlite` file. In order to check if things are working at this stage I created a small table using NetBeans' user interface, added a bunch of stuff and then using the terminal checked if the database file has changed and what it contains. No problems here.
3. **Resolve Maven dependecies** - to the `<dependencies/>` inside the `pom.xml` of my project I added:

   ```
   <dependencies>

     <!-- various other dependencies mostly related to Vaadin -->
     ...

     <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
       <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.2</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
       <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.2</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
       <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
       <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.2</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```
4. **Created a persistence unit** - I have 3 entity classes - `User`, `Ingredient` and `Recipe`. The generated `persistence.xml` contains:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="CookbookPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
       <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
       <non-jta-data-source>cookbook_db</non-jta-data-source>
       <class>com.ava.cookbook.models.User</class>
       <class>com.ava.cookbook.models.Ingredient</class>
       <class>com.ava.cookbook.models.Recipe</class>
       <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
       <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:/PATH_TO_PROJECT_ROOT/cookbook_db.sqlite"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="cookbook"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="cookbook"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
       </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
   ```

Note that the **schema generation** is set to `drop-and-create`.

Basically these are my settings. When I try to run the project in the output window four new tabs appear:

- **Run (Cookbook)** - this one tells me information about the state of the running project (since I haven't started actually accessing the database (which I cannot connect to :3) it runs perfectly fine)
- **GlassFish Server 4.1** - information about the GlassFish server that the project is running on
- **Browser Log** - I'm using the NetBeans connector and while running the Vaadin project inside Google Chrome this tab displays a bunch of Vaadin-related events
- **Java DB Database Process** - this one is the bummer in all this. In detail the messages here are:

  ```
  Fri Oct 09 15:02:47 CEST 2015 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
  Fri Oct 09 15:02:48 CEST 2015 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.11.1.2 - (1629631) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
  ```

Before I saw that I was thinking that I've screwed things up with the whole JPA-Entity-thing but after I noticed the second message in particular it became obvious that the project not connecting to the SQLite database but running it's own Derby DB.

I have barely any experience with Maven, EclipseLink, JPA and NetBeans so it is quite possible I'm overlooking something. Some advice or even a solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the connection is already setup incorrectly.

1. Use the Netbeans Menu : Windows -> Services to show the services tab.
2. Expand Servers
3. Expand GlassFish Server
4. Expand Resources
5. Expand JDBC
6. Expand JDBC Resources
7. Select your resource name.
8. Right-click for properties. Note the Pool Name
9. Expand Connection Pools
10. Select the Pool you just noted.
11. Right-click for properties.
12. Edit properties to use sqlite instead of derby. URL should be `jdbc:sqlite:<path to cookbook.sqlite>`

If you haven't setup the resource.

1. Select your project.
2. Right-click for New -> Other
3. In the Dialog select Category = Glassfish, File Type = JDBC Resource
4. Select Create New JDBC Connection Pool.
5. Change the name to your resources name
6. Click Next Twice
7. Set the Connection Pool name to something that  you can remember.
8. Set the Data Source CLass Name to anything you want.
9. Set the Resource Type javax.sql.ConnectiPoolDataSource
10. Click Next
11. Check the settings on the last screen of the dialog and then click Finish.

To create classes mapped to tables:

1. Select your project.
2. Right-click for New -> Other
3. In the Dialog select Category = Persistance, File Type =  Entity Class
4. Change Class name and Package Name

There are some tutorials that would probably be worth while to quickly work through even though they also cover some irrelevant material they are not that long.

[Getting Started with Java EE Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted.html)
[Creating a Simple Web Application Using a MySQL Database](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/mysql-webapp.html)

and/or

Take a look at the sample, at File > New Project > Samples > Java EE > Web JPA

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I didn't have my cookbook_db inside the JDBC Resources. Tried various things in order to add it but at the end reinstalling the server did register the DB (really weird). I also had to manually edit the `glassfish-resources.xml`. Now at least the Derby isn't starting. However JPA doesn't seem to be generating my tables. In Eclipse I could just use the project's context menu and go to `JPA Tools` and from there select the generation of tables options. However in NetBeans there is no such thing. I read that it is supposed to do it automatically but not in my case. Any idea?

Comment: I am not certain what the problem is but I have tried to document and provide some possible hints.

Comment: The problem is that unlike an Eclipse project (Vaadin using Ivy) in NetBeans I have no idea how to generate tne DB tables from my entities automatically. I have looked into multiple tutorials but still...As for the NetBeans sample JPA project - it's no good since it doesn't use Maven or Ivy, which makes it impossible for me to integrate it with Vaadin (probably possible but the amount of work would be too much). I have also successfully created multiple JPA project in Eclipse so I do have some knowledge about the whole entity thing. The NetBeans CRUD example (JPA+Maven) is too extensive.

Comment: [This feature](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks007.htm) is what I'm looking for in NetBeans but cannot find. As mentioned I have set the table generation strategy in my `persistence.xml` to `drop-and-create` but I have no idea how to activate it. I've read it's supposed to be triggered automatically when you run the project but that is not the case with mine.

Comment: After struggling quite a bit I switched to Tomcat 8. Had to fix this and that and also add the `sqlite-jdbc` to the `pom.xml` as dependency but now it's all good. Also I found why actually GlassFish is starting automatically Derby - when you go to the properties of the server there is actually a checkbox that does that. :D